# Git updates submodule with an unamed branch

Tags: git

I've used git for quite a bit now but stayed away from submodules since I didn't had a good reason to use them. However, recently I began a project which clearly needs to use this feature of git.

However, each time I clone the entire project the submodule ends in a branch with no name. Here are the commands I execute:

```
git clone <url to project>
git submodule update --init <submodule>
cd <submodule>; git branch
```

and it prints out:

```
* (no branch)
  master
```

I need to do an additional

```
git checkout master
```

Now my question is: is this the standard behavior? If not, can you help me out understanding what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike some other SCMs, commits in Git do not inherently belong to any particular branch. A branch head is like a bookmark for a commit. When you have a branch checked out (i.e. the file `.git/HEAD` contains a reference to the branch), and you make a commit, Git moves that bookmark forward to point to the new commit.

But this tracking behaviour doesn't apply here. As you may already know, a submodule is pinned to a particular commit; it does not track a branch head. When you update a submodule, Git checks out *that particular commit* only. That means `.git/HEAD` contains the commit hash, not a branch ref.

There may be one or more branch heads pointing to this commit, but that's kind of irrelevant. Only when `HEAD` contains a branch ref, not a commit hash, will `git branch` show you are on a branch.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I didn't know that submodules were pinned to a specific commit and now that you've explained it, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Is there a way to make this 'git checkout master' happen automatically though? It has caused me hours of frustration, and I don't see a reason not to make it checkout master by default.

Comment: I have also been frustrated by this `git` behavior! How can we not use `git checkout <branch>` from the very beginning?